# Compare two Doctrine_Record objects

Tags: doctrine, comparison

How do I compare two `Doctrine_Record` objects to see if they are "equal"?

On the domain login I am considering, two objects are equal if they have the same properties values, except the `id` and the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields (a la `Timestampable`).

Answer (score 0):

First idea which comes into my mind is:

```
class User extends Doctrine_Record
{
  public function equals(User $user)
  {
    $left = $this->toArray();
    $right = $user->toArray();

    unset($left['id'], $left['created_at'], $left['updated_at']);
    unset($right['id'], $right['created_at'], $right['updated_at']);

    return $left == $right;
  }
}
```