# Does symfony have a built-in method for comparing tainted values to the original?

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine

I am using symfony 1.4 with Doctrine.  I have built a form which uses a table that has the Versionable behaviour.  As expected, Versionable creates a new version of the row every time the form is submitted and saved.  My problem is that I would like to prevent it doing so if the actual values submitted are not any different from the original values put into the form via the edit action.

I know that I can do this with javascript relatively easily.  I'm just curious as to whether symfony or Doctrine have this functionality already, and how it is used if so.  It just seems like something that symfony would have a method for, which could be checked right before `$form->save()` is called.  Am I dreaming or perhaps missing something obvious?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. If data doesn't change, neither Versionable nor Timestable react when you save your form. Maybe you have override Model::save() and something changes your data?

Comment: I haven't done anything to override `save()`, but it definitely does create a new version regardless of whether anything has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DoctrineRecord::getModified()` function which returns an array of the modified fields and associated values from an overridden `save()` function or in a listener (`preSave` would be the best I guess).
If the new values are not any different, you can bypass the actual call to `save()`, so no new version is created.

Comment: This was quite a while ago, but I think this is more or less what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

The comment for the `save()` method of the Doctrine_Record is

```
/**
 * applies the changes made to this object into database
 * this method is smart enough to know if any changes are made
 * and whether to use INSERT or UPDATE statement
 *
 * this method also saves the related components
 *
 * @param Doctrine_Connection $conn     optional connection parameter
 * @throws Exception                    if record is not valid and validation is active
 * @return void
 */
```

so first, you should check whether it does not already work.
If not, Doctrine_Record has a isModified() method you could use. If the `bind()` method of the form object modifies the object in the form which should at first contain the default values, then this method should return true.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but `$form->getObject()->isModified()` always returns false after the `bind()`.  Am I perhaps using the wrong syntax?

Comment: Also, the `save()` method is definitely creating a new version by default with the Versionable behaviour, even when nothing has changed.

Comment: Before the `bind()`, does the form object contain the default values?

Comment: Yes it does.  `$form->getObject()->getRevisionName()` (for example) returns the default value of that field both before and after `bind()`.  Does this mean I need to override the default `save()` then or go with a jQuery solution?

Comment: Then I misunderstood how bind() works. You may do a check in the preSave() hook, here is how you compare two records : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874524/doctrine-compare-two-objects

Comment: BTW, you can still debug what happened using the `getModified()` method on the form object to see what exactly was modified.

Comment: This is quite old, but if you don't want to override `save()` method and instead stay with `$form->bind()` you can do so by afterwards calling `$form->updateObject()`. This will apply the new values to the object without saving them yet. You can then check changes by `$form->getObject()->getModified()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override `save()` method or implement a listener as jaudette suggested you can instead stay with form binding:

```
$form->bind($values);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $form->updateObject();
    $changes = $form->getObject()->getModified();

    // save to database if desired
    $form->save();
}
```

The object will not be saved to database by calling `$form->updateObject()`, but the actual php object is changed.
Also note that you might have to call `getModified()` on each related object if you have embedded subforms.